# Liking a youtube comment with selenium

Tags: php, selenium, youtube

I am trying to vote-up a `YouTube` comment with `Selenium` and `PHP`, I am using `Facebook Webdriver`.

My problem is that click doesn't do anything, it works on any other website but not on `YouTube` up voting.

I am using Selenium 3.4.0 with `geckodriver` and `firefox` 55.0.3 on `Windows 10`
my code is like this :

```
Login
Go to the comment url 
Scroll down and wait comments to show up
$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("(//a[contains(@class, 'comment-author-text') and contains(text(),'channelname')]/following::button[contains(@class, 'i-a-v-sprite-like')])[1]"));

$element->click();
```

I tried `$driver->getMouse()` but it is not working.

After some search I found out that it can't work with my setup , and I need to downgrade selenium, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: "After some search I found out that it can't work with my setup , and I need to downgrade selenium, but I don't want to do that". You kind of answered your own question. Upgrade your stuff, or downgrade selenium.

Comment: I need to downgrade, to order to use mouse move, But I don't want to do that

Comment: Why doesn't the new Selenium work? What old stuff is holding it back?

Comment: @delboy1978uk Basicaly anything related to remotemouse don't work with the new version

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my linked comment drive me right to the reply box, So I had to close that first (using cancel button) and after that I was able to like the comment